# Using react-router in a Microsoft Office add-in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, ms-office, office-addins

I am building a Microsoft office add-in and using React. Usually, the navigation on the web is done using `react-router-dom`. However, I am not able to initialize the `HashRouter` in the index.js file, since it gives me only a white page. I am not sure where the bug is, since it is extremely difficult to debug apps for Office.

Did anyone encounter the same problem?

```
import App from "./components/App";
import { AppContainer } from "react-hot-loader";
import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/font-icons-mdl2";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

/* global document, Office, module, require */

initializeIcons();

let isOfficeInitialized = false;

const title = "Contoso Task Pane Add-in";

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("container")
  );
};

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.onReady(() => {
  isOfficeInitialized = true;
  render(App);
});

/* Initial render showing a progress bar */
render(App);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./components/App", () => {
    const NextApp = require("./components/App").default;
    render(NextApp);
  });
}
```

I tried changing the render method to

```
const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />} />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("container")
  );
};
```

This does not solve the issue, however. I am using `react@17` and `react-router-dom@6`.

Comment: So now that you've fixed the `Route` component issue what exactly are you experiencing when rendering the app and navigating to the `"/"` path?

Comment: @DrewReese: still the white page.

Comment: Do you have any debugging details? Are there any errors when building or in the browser console when running? Can you inspect the DOM to see what is rendered there?

Comment: I am sideloading the app in a word document and not running it in the browser. Therefore, I cannot debug it through the console. I created the first version in the browser (for debugging), but the browser-router worked there, and now I can't run it and also cannot debug it.

Comment: If you are not running the app in a browser context then you might want to use a `MemoryRouter` so there isn't any coupling between a URL in an address bar and what the app/router will try to match.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for your help. I managed to fix the problem, however not with MemoryRouter. If the question gets reopened, I will post my answer here.

Comment: The question is reopened, I'm interested in your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the help of the comments provided by Drew Reese. The problem was two-fold:

- The `BrowserRouter` component does not work in a Microsoft Office Add-In. We need to use `HashRouter` instead.
- The routing pattern used in the newest `react-router-dom@6` library does not work with `react@17` in a Microsoft Office Add-In. We need to use `react-router-dom@5` instead, which uses the `<Switch />` component for routing.

The code in `index.js` looks like this:

```
import App from "./main/App";
import { AppContainer } from "react-hot-loader";
import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/font-icons-mdl2";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";

/* global document, Office, module, require */

initializeIcons();

let isOfficeInitialized = false;

const title = "Cool title";

const render = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
          <Component title={title} isOfficeInitialized={isOfficeInitialized} />
        </HashRouter>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("container")
  );
};

/* Render application after Office initializes */
Office.onReady(() => {
  isOfficeInitialized = true;
  render(App);
});

/* Initial render showing a progress bar */
render(App);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./main/App", () => {
    const NextApp = require("./main/App").default;
    render(NextApp);
  });
}
```

And the actual routing is implement in `App.js` and looks like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>App Title</h1>
      <Stack>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <div>Hello World</div>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/main">
            <div>Hello Main</div>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Stack>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;

App.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  isOfficeInitialized: PropTypes.bool,
};
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "routing patterns changed in `react-router-dom@6`? Just about anything you can do in RRDv5 you can do in RRDv6.

Comment: The newest release does not use the `<Switch />` component anymore. Instead, the routes are created with the `createBrowserRouter()` method and saved in the router object, which is then passed as a prop to the `<RouterProvider />` component.

Comment: Right, the `Switch` component was replaced by a `Routes` component.

Answer (score 0):

Strongly suspect this is due to serving your add-in over an unsecure connection which will render a white screen and provide little signs of what's wrong until it's fixed.

Ensure you are serving your app over a secure (HTTPS) connection. Office addins will not render unless they are served over a secured connection and react apps do not default to serving over a local secure connection.

If you're testing your addin locally on your machine, you'll need to setup your local environment to serve securely as if it was going over HTTPS. Typically this involves generating security certificates and a few other steps described decently well in [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-react-js-use-https-in-development-4ead560eff10).

Fortunately, Microsoft has saved you some trouble and provided a couple handy libraries to shortcut this process.

First ensure you have installed the following dev packages:

```
"office-addin-debugging": "^4.6.7",
"office-addin-dev-certs": "^1.11.1"
```

Second, in your package.json file, you'll want to modify your start script so that it utilises office-addin-debugging as such:

```
"scripts": {

    "start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml", <---TRY THIS!
    "start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",
    "start:web": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web",
    "stop": "office-addin-debugging stop manifest.xml",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch"
  },
```

Third, add a config section to your package.json file just before your scripts section like so:

```
 "config": {
    "app_to_debug": "excel",
    "app_type_to_debug": "desktop",
    "dev_server_port": 3000
  },
  "scripts": {
```

Then, in theory when you run npm run start, you will be prompted to install security certificates and an instance of excel will automatically launch, ideally with your addin that is now working... Good luck!

**For Next.JS users:** if you're building an addin using next.js rather than just react, you can still rely on office-add-in-dev-certs, but you'll need to do one extra step and write your own server. Easier than it sounds. Simply, install the same office-addin-dev-certs package I note above, add a file called server.js to the root of your project and include the following code:

```
const { createServer } = require('https')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
const devCerts = require('office-addin-dev-certs')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const options = await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions()

  createServer(options, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

      if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
      res.statusCode = 500
      res.end('internal server error')
    }
  }).listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on https://${hostname}:${port}`)
  })
})
```